# undetected_chromedriver add a plugin

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, plugins, webbrowser-control, undetected-chromedriver

I want to add a plugin to the undetected_chromedriver driver, just like in google chrome. I did some research and tried to add it with a crx file, but I could not succeed. can you help me with this.

**codes i tried**

```
opts.add_extension('Extention/YoutubeforAdblock.crx')
```

```
opts.add_argument('--load-extension=/Extention/YoutubeforAdblock.crx')
```

I tried to add a plugin for the undetected_chromedriver web browser. I'm asking how this should be done.

```
enter code here
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

opts = uc.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("--window-size=1020,900")
opts.add_extension('Extention/YoutubeforAdblock.crx')

driver = uc.Chrome(options=opts,use_subprocess=True)
driver.get('https://google.com')`
```

**plugin i want to add**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-for-youtube/cmedhionkhpnakcndndgjdbohmhepckk?hl=tr

Comment: Please add in a full reproducible code so others can run the code for debugging. Also if there are any errors from your run, please state it as well

Comment: edit was made. so do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.crx files are just like .zip files.**

You need to extract the crx file to use it with the undetected driver.

*1.*
Download your crx file in zip with a tool like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda?hl=tr

*2.*
extract anywhere. like C:\Users\username\Desktop\extension
**(extension is folder)**

*3.*
finally add it to your code:

`opts.add_argument('--load-extension=C:\Users\username\Desktop\extension')`